# Parse data from aws s3 bucket and save parsed data to another bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS S3, and I was reading to this tutorial from AWS on how to move data from bucket to another

[How can I copy objects between Amazon S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-objects-s3-bucket/)

However, I didn't notice, or it didn't mention that you can apply a hook or any intermediate step before data will be saved.

Ideally, we wanted to take the data from a log bucket(its very dirty and wanted to clean it up a bit) and save another copy of it in another S3 (the parsed data). We also wanted to do this periodically so that automation would be necessary for the future.

What I wanted to know is that,  can I do this with just S3 or do I need to use another service to do the parsing and saving to another bucket.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change the actual data in the files or just the structure of the files in S3?

Answer (score 3):

S3 by itself is simply for storage. You should be looking at [using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).

Every time a file is pushed to your Log bucket, S3 can trigger a Lambda function (that you write) that can read the file, do the clean up, and then push the cleaned data to the new S3 bucket.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To expand on this one... Rather than thinking of doing something periodically, the above method will activate an AWS Lambda function as soon as the log file is placed into the Amazon S3 bucket. Therefore, there is no need to activate code at regular times. The Lambda function can be written in the language of your choice, and can run for up to 15 minutes. It has a limitation of temporary 500MB of disk space, but your log files should not be that big.